# How can I use a foreach loop and set small variations at fixed positions?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I already search for long time on this forum and I can't find a solution to this problem.

I need to create a `foreach` loop for 12 elements but 3 of them have different class.

This is what I have done so far:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT `views` FROM `views` WHERE `views` = `id` AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= date(`views`.`time`) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 12");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $users[] = $row;
}

$output .= '<ul>';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $output .= '<li class="grid__item"></li>';
}
$output .= '<ul>';

return $output;
```

How can I add a different class to `li` objects at 2, 8 and 12 position?

To output something like this:

```
<ul>                    
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item grid__item--deco grid__item--deco-1"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item grid__item--deco grid__item--deco-2"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item"></li>
    <li class="grid__item grid__item--deco grid__item--deco-3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Is there some data value that you need to evaluate based on? This is far too vague to answer.

Comment: @Blake What I'm able to do is this `foreach($rows as $row) {}; `...the problem is that all list objects have the same class

Comment: You question isn't clear, when do the extra classes `grid__item--deco grid__item--deco-2` need to be added.

Comment: @EvanTaylor thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `key` of `foreach`, then set the additional class inside the loop block. Just add an `if` condition:

```
$i = 1;
$class_keys = array(2, 8, 12);
$output = '<ul>';
foreach($rows as $key => $row) {
              //  ^ use this
    $default_class = 'grid__item';
    if(in_array($key + 1, $class_keys)) {
        $default_class .= " grid__item--deco grid__item--deco-{$i}";
        $i++;
    }
    $output .= "<li class=\"$default_class\"></li>";

}
$output .= '<ul>';
```

Comment: @Simone sure no prob

Answer (score 1):

If they are always 2, 8 and 12:

```
$rowcount = 1;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if ($rowcount == 2 || $rowcount == 8 || $rowcount == 12) {
        $output .= '<li class="grid__item"></li>';
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<li class="OTHER CLASS"></li>';
    }
    $rowcount ++;
}
```

Seems clunky to me but maybe that will work.